# Python Pandas Append List of Dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, append

This is a sort of simple question but I don't think it has been asked before.

If I have a list of dataframes (they need to be in this format because of multiprocessing),

```
df_list=[df1,df2,...,dfn]
```

Is there an elegant way to append all of them? A one liner would be even better.

Comment: Did you look at [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following parallel processing example works in [IPython](http://ipython.org) by using concat method:

```
    from IPython import parallel
    clients = parallel.Client() #a lightweight handle on all the engines of a cluster
    clients.block = True  # use synchronous computations
    print(clients.ids)

    dview = clients[:] #dview = clients.direct_view()
    dview.block = True

    dview.scatter("experiment", myDataFrame) # <myDataFrame> scattered as <experiment> to the engines
    dview["wlist_ptrn"] = wlist_ptrn
    dview.execute("experiment['allFeats'] = experiment.ttext.str.findall(wlist_ptrn)")
    return pd.concat(dview.gather("experiment")) # gather method returns a list of data frames
```

I hope it can be useful for the multiprocessing module output.